# Check each booleans in an object

Tags: javascript, object, boolean

I have an object called timers. In Timers I have two other objects, active and roomTime.

using `timers.active` returns a room name and boolean like this:

```
{room1: true, room2: true, room3: false}
```

using `timers.roomTime` returns a number like so:

```
{room1: 0, room2: 8, room3: 65}
```

My question is: how do I make a function that when used checks each `timers.active` for `true`, and if `true` does a ++ on its number in `timers.roomTime`?

For context, I want to use `myFunction()` and make it add 1 to room1 and room2, since they're both true. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (**Edit:** noticed you wanted to use `myFunction` for this. Well, you should figure it out by yourself based on this code):

```
// setup
timers = {};
timers.active = {room1: true, room2: true, room3: false};
timers.roomTime = {room1: 0, room2: 8, room3: 65};

// filter for active rooms
const activeRooms = Object.keys(timers.roomTime).filter((key) => timers.active[key]);

// mutate roomTime based on active rooms
activeRooms.forEach((roomId) => timers.roomTime[roomId]++);
```

Comment: Thanks man that was fast. I didn't even finish cooking breakfast yet and you already got it back to me. Cheers!